# After pseduo class in IE11 with background fade

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm getting a weird result in IE11 (surprise) with a background image fade.

I have this for my CSS:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 400px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.parent::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, #FFF) left repeat;
    background: linear-gradient(transparent, #FFF) left repeat;
    min-height: inherit;
  }
```

But when I check it out in IE11 it *sorta* works but I'm getting this hard line down the image:

[image]

Not sure what I'm missing?

Comment: What happens when you add `left:0` to `.parent::after`? IF that doesn't fix it, please provide enough code to show your issue.

Comment: can you post the Enough code (include the related html code) to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Adding a `left:0` fixed it. Thanks! @Kravimir